# Preserve backslash in $1

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that accepts a parameter ($1) with backslashes and I want my script to echo the parameter ($1) exactly with the backslashes entered back.

e.g.

```
$ ./tst \\abc\def\ghi\jkl\lmn\
\\abc\def\ghi\jkl\lmn\
```

My tst script at present looks like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

When I run my script it returns;

```
\abcdefghijkllmn
```

I want it to return:

```
\\abc\def\ghi\jkl\lmn\
```

Exactly what I entered. I've even tried `echo -E $1` but that made no difference.

Any suggestions I could achieve my desirable returned output from my script would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try passing the parameter(s) to your script using single quotes (').  Without that, your shell is eating them before your script even sees the parameter.

```
$ ./tst '\\abc\def\ghi\jkl\lmn\'
```

Comment: You script should also use `echo "$1"`; unquoted, the shell will process `$1` before passing the result to `echo`.